# Swift structures causing undefined behaviour

Tags: objective-c, swift, struct, metal

I'm writing a program that uses Metal. I'm defining the uniform buffer layout using a structure. When I declare the struct in swift, it fails to draw. But when I declare the struct in Objective-C and use a bridging header to import it, it works fine. The actual logic for computations are exactly the same. The only change is the declaration. Here are the declarations:

Objective-C declaration (this one works):

```
struct Uniforms {
    struct Matrix4x4 modelViewMatrix;
    struct Matrix4x4 projectionMatrix;
    struct Matrix3x3 normalMatrix;
    struct Vector3 lightPosition;
};
```

And the Swift declaration:

```
struct Uniforms {
    var modelViewMatrix: Matrix4x4!
    var projectionMatrix: Matrix4x4!
    var normalMatrix: Matrix3x3!
    var lightPosition: Vector3!
}
```

Note that the math types are structs defined in Objective-C, and act as wrappers for Swift.

For more info, here is the Swift code that computes the values and sends them to Metal:

```
// Declaration:
var uniforms: Uniforms!
...
// Part where I compute the values:
    self.uniforms = Uniforms()

    let eye = vector3Create(0.0, 5.0, 7.0)
    let center = vector3Create(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    let up = vector3Create(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    self.uniforms.modelViewMatrix = MathOperations.lookAt(eye, center: center, up: up)

    let aspect = Float(self.view.bounds.size.width / self.view.bounds.size.height)
    self.uniforms.projectionMatrix = MathOperations.perspective(45.0, aspect: aspect, near: 0.01, far: 100.0)
    self.uniforms.normalMatrix = getMatrix3x3FromMatrix4x4(self.uniforms.modelViewMatrix)
    self.uniforms.lightPosition = vector3Create(0.0, 5.0, 7.0)

    self.vertexBuffer = device.newBufferWithBytes(self.vertexArray, length: self.vertexArray.count * sizeof(Float), options: .CPUCacheModeDefaultCache)
    self.uniformBuffer = device.newBufferWithBytes(&self.uniforms, length: sizeof(Uniforms), options: .CPUCacheModeDefaultCache)
```

Sorry for all the code, but please help. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you making the 4 fields in the Swift struct optionals?

Comment: Thanks! I made them optional at first because I thought that since they start out with a declaration, it needs to be nil at first. But now I made them non-nullable, and filled up the struct with a constructor. Now it works! On a side note, why doesn't Metal accept optionals? The GPU frame capture shows the correct data in the buffers even when optional.

Comment: Good, I added more info as an answer. Please accept it if it does solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to explain here the comment I added to the question and that looks to be a correct answer.

The correct way to convert this `Objective-C` code:

```
struct Matrix4x4 modelViewMatrix;
```

to `Swift` is **NOT** this

```
var modelViewMatrix: Matrix4x4!
```

because this way we are not creating variable of type `Matrix4x4`. Instead we are creating a variable of type `Optional` of type `Matrix4x4`.

This means that in Swift the variable `modelViewMatrix` is able to assume `nil` value while in Objective-C it does not.

> Let's remember that in Objective-C a variable having a struct as type
>   cannot be nil.

So the correct way to translate the original statement from `Objective-C` to `Swift` is the following:

```
var modelViewMatrix: Matrix4x4
```